# DOM selecting elements that are visible in a dom-if

Tags: polymer-1.0

I'd like for a way to select only visible elements in the DOM that are within a  template that evaluates to true.

```
<template is="dom-if" if="[[true]]">
  <span>I should be selectable</span>
</template>
<template is="dom-if" if="[[false]]">
  <span>I should not be selectable</span>
</template>
```

I'm currently using this:

```
Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll("span");
```

which also returns nodes that are in `<dom-if>` templates that evaluate to false.

Is there any to do this *without* using `restamp`?

Comment: I think that's the default. If the expression evaluates to `false` the element is remove from the DOM and can't be queried anymore. Where do you execute the code line that you have in your question?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer  The element is only removed from the DOM if `restamp` is set on the `<dom-if>` - which I'd like to avoid

Comment: Right. Didn't know that. It's a while I used Polymer.

Comment: I guess you need to filter the search by the hidden attribute `!hidden`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer That won't work - I'm wrapping the elements in a `<dom-if>` to hide them. That would only work if I directly set on *each* element the hidden attribute. `hidden` is not automatically set when wrapped in dom-ifs

Comment: Are you sure? The `dom-if` docs say without `restamp` it's hidden. It's quite unlikely they introduced some custom method to hide the element.

Comment: Positive - I've tried quering for the `hidden` attribute on non-visible elements just now - as for the second part of your comment, they actually did, see: https://plus.google.com/+GerwinSturm/posts/VAPHZjsubKm

Comment: They set the display property https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/ff6e884ef4f309d41491333860a8bc9c2f178696/src/lib/template/templatizer.html#L162 then you can check for `display != 'none'`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer That's also going to prevent selection of items that are not in the `dom-if` and just have their CSS prop set as such - I'm looking for a more surefire way that's directly connected to the `dom-if` template - I'm getting convinced there's no such way

Comment: As you see in the code that's all Polymer does. `restamp` is surefire. You can try to add a property `<span ishidden="[[false]]">` by binding the same value used for `if="..."` and then check if this property is set to `'false'`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thought about that already but I've got too many elements wrapped in the `dom-if` and I'd like to avoid that kind of duplication - I think it might be better to implement my own `<dom-if>` via the `Templatizer` which would auto-manage that for me, i.e setting a `not-visible` attribute on the hidden elements